# Error method is undefinded for type Character

Tags: java, character

I have a program that finds the number of times that four letters occur in a `.txt` file and I cannot figure out why it is giving me this error:

```
Error: The method isWhiteSpace(char) is undefined for the type java.lang.Character
```

What does this error mean, what is causing this problem, and how do I fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException {

  String phrase;
  String everything = "";  // a string of characters
  int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
  int length;       // the length of the phrase
  char ch;          // an individual character in the string
  int countA;
  int countE;
  int countS;
  int countT;

  java.io.File file = new java.io.File("counting.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 phrase = inFile.nextLine();
 length = phrase.length();

      // Initialize counts

  while (true)
  { 
  if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))

      break;

  else
  {

  countBlank = 0;
  countA = 0;
  countE = 0;
  countS = 0;
  countT = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )   
   { 
   if ( phrase.charAt( i ) == ' ' )

    countBlank++;
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);

       switch (ch)
        {
         case 'a':
         case 'A':  countA++;
                 break;
     case 'e':
     case 'E':  countE++;
         break;
     case 's':
     case 'S':  countS++;
            break;
     case 't':
     case 'T':  countT++;
        break;
      }

 }
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println ();

    System.out.println ("Number of A's: " + countA);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of E's: " + countE);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of S's: " + countS);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of T's: " + countT);
    break;

  }     
 }


 } 
}
```

Comment: It's `isWhitespace`, not `isWhiteSpace`. Java is case sensitive. Look into javadoc.

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Letter case is significant in Java; check the javadocs for the correct method name.

Comment: How is that code producing that error?  The specific method isn't even being called in that code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo it is [Character.isWhitespace(ch);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)

Answer (score 0):

The method `isWhiteSpace(char)` accepts an argument whose type is `char`, not `Character`.

`Character` is an object and `char` is a native type.

If `char1` is the object of type `Character`, then use this code:

```
//Assume char1 is an object of type Character
boolean flagWS;
flagWS = Character.isWhiteSpace(char1.charValue())
```